# ¿Por qué no puedo ubicar mi logo usando position en css?

Tags: html, css

Tengo este código y quiero que el `div id="fb"` se posicione encima de la imagen que uso como banner (`img src="baner3.png"`) para que redireccione a una página de Facebook al hacerle `click`. Sin embargo siempre aparece bajo el banner.

Código:

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 1365px;
  font-family: century;
  font-size: 20.05px;
}

ul,
il {
  list-style: none;
}

.nave li a {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 5px;
  background-color: rgb( 0, 0, 0);
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.nave>li {
  float: left;
}

.nave li a:hover {
  background-color: rgb( 242, 179, 44);
}

p {
  background: white;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

.loren {
  position: relative;
  top: 227px;
  left: 850px;
  padding: 20px;
}

li ul li {
  display: block;
}

.header ul li a ul li {
  display: none
}

.fb {
  position: relative top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<a href="codigo 1,inicio.html">
  <img src="baner3.png" height="200px" width="1366px" title="inicio" />
</a>

<div id="header">
  <ul class="nave">
    <li> <a href="codigo 1,inicio.html"> INICIO </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="seccion 1.xml"> NOSOTROS</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="new 1.html">CONTRA EDITORIAL PRIMATE </a>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="articulos.html."> ARTICULOS </a> </li>
        <li> <a href? "publicaciones.html">PUBLICACIONES </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="columnas.html">COLUMNAS </a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="primatetv.html">  PRIMATE TV </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="radio primate.html"> RADIO PRIMATE </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="tienda.html"> TIENDA </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="donaciones.html">DONACIONES </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="contactanos.html">CONTACTANOS </a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="fb">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Tr%C3%ADada-Primate-1006588336127088/?ref=aymt_homepage_panel">
    <img src="facebook-icon-preview-1-400x400.png" height="30px" width="30px" title="fb primate">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: El `div` con id "fb", ¿está dentro o fuera del `div id="header"`? Al código que compartes le falta un cierre de `div` y no queda claro dónde iría.

Comment: Aparte, ¿por qué no directamente cambiar el `href` del enlace que contiene la imagen del logo? ¿No tienes control sobre el HTML?

Comment: esta fuera del id="header"

Comment: al hacer click en el banner busco que se redireccione a la pagina de inicio, pero ademas, deseo , encima del banner poner un logo de fb que redireccione a una pagina de fb . soy nuevo en esto, siento las molestias

Comment: ¿Entonces quieres que al pulsar sobre el banner ocurran dos acciones (ir a inicio + ir a facebook)? Porque si es eso, vas a necesitar JavaScript

Comment: no, quiero que al hacer click en el banner se redireccione a la pagina de inicio, pero tambien encima del banner colocar el logo de fb y al hacer click en el logo de fb se redireccione a la pagina de facebook, ¿es posible eso? en todo caso, tendre que poner el logo de fb con su link al final de mi web y no en el banner

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo, tienes tres bloques:
El banner
El header
El logo

Si pones al logo position:relative, seguira en el mismo flujo. Osea mantendrá la posición y se le respetara su espacio. Por lo que seguirá estando debajo del header.

Por otra parte en el css para llamar a los id se hace con # y a las clases con "." por lo que sería #fb{ ... }

También he cambiado el bloque de posición para que este justo antes que el banner.

De todos modos, quizas un position:absolute; te vendría mejor para evitar que se le tenga en cuenta en el flujo.

(http://es.learnlayout.com/position.html)

Por otra parte, te voy a recomendar el uso de Display:flex; para casi todo. No te sirve para el caso en concreto, pero por el tema del menu, que lo tienes con floats, muchas veces dan problemas con las pantallas responsive. Mira https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ en 4 lineas habrás hecho lo mimso, sin que nada sea flotante.

(En el padre que contiene los items a ordenar)
display:flex;
flex-direcction: row;

Y ya los tienes todos en una linea.

Un saludo, y espero haber podido ayudar.

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 1365px;
  font-family: century;
  font-size: 20.05px;
}

ul,
il {
  list-style: none;
}

.nave li a {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 5px;
  background-color: rgb( 0, 0, 0);
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.nave>li {
  float: left;
}

.nave li a:hover {
  background-color: rgb( 242, 179, 44);
}

p {
  background: white;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

.loren {
  position: relative;
  top: 227px;
  left: 850px;
  padding: 20px;
}

li ul li {
  display: block;
}

.header ul li a ul li {
  display: none
}

#fb {
  position: relative;
  top: -150px;
}
```

```html
<a href="codigo 1,inicio.html">
  <img src="baner3.png" height="200px" width="1366px" title="inicio" />
</a>

<div id="fb">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Tr%C3%ADada-Primate-1006588336127088/?ref=aymt_homepage_panel">
    <img src="facebook-icon-preview-1-400x400.png" height="30px" width="30px" title="fb primate">
  </a>
</div>

<div id="header">
  <ul class="nave">
    <li> <a href="codigo 1,inicio.html"> INICIO </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="seccion 1.xml"> NOSOTROS</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="new 1.html">CONTRA EDITORIAL PRIMATE </a>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="articulos.html."> ARTICULOS </a> </li>
        <li> <a href? "publicaciones.html">PUBLICACIONES </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="columnas.html">COLUMNAS </a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="primatetv.html">  PRIMATE TV </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="radio primate.html"> RADIO PRIMATE </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="tienda.html"> TIENDA </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="donaciones.html">DONACIONES </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="contactanos.html">CONTACTANOS </a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, lo que tienes que hacer son varias cosas:

1. Tu div fb, es un id no una clas, en el css tienes que llamarle con #.
2. En cada propiedad CSS debes poner ; al final.
3. En mi opinión usaría `position: relative;`

La parte a modificar sería esta, quedando así:

```
#fb {
  position: absolute; top: 150px;
}
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda, saludos!!

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 1365px;
  font-family: century;
  font-size: 20.05px;
}

ul,
il {
  list-style: none;
}

.nave li a {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 5px;
  background-color: rgb( 0, 0, 0);
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.nave>li {
  float: left;
}

.nave li a:hover {
  background-color: rgb( 242, 179, 44);
}

p {
  background: white;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

.loren {
  position: relative;
  top: 227px;
  left: 850px;
  padding: 20px;
}

li ul li {
  display: block;
}

.header ul li a ul li {
  display: none
}

#fb {
  position: absolute; top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<a href="codigo 1,inicio.html">
  <img src="baner3.png" height="200px" width="1366px" title="inicio" />
</a>

<div id="header">
  <ul class="nave">
    <li> <a href="codigo 1,inicio.html"> INICIO </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="seccion 1.xml"> NOSOTROS</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="new 1.html">CONTRA EDITORIAL PRIMATE </a>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="articulos.html."> ARTICULOS </a> </li>
        <li> <a href? "publicaciones.html">PUBLICACIONES </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="columnas.html">COLUMNAS </a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="primatetv.html">  PRIMATE TV </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="radio primate.html"> RADIO PRIMATE </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="tienda.html"> TIENDA </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="donaciones.html">DONACIONES </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="contactanos.html">CONTACTANOS </a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="fb">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Tr%C3%ADada-Primate-1006588336127088/?ref=aymt_homepage_panel">
    <img src="facebook-icon-preview-1-400x400.png" height="30px" width="30px" title="fb primate">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Por reputación no puedo comentar, así que aquí solución:

Si no tienes acceso al HTML, aquí está la posible solución:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
  body {
  background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 1365px;
  font-family: century;
  font-size: 20.05px;
}

ul,li {
  list-style: none;
}

.nave li a {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 5px;
  background-color: rgb( 0, 0, 0);
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.nave>li {
  float: left;
}

.nave li a:hover {
  background-color: rgb( 242, 179, 44);
}

p {
  background: white;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

.loren {
  position: relative;
  top: 227px;
  left: 850px;
  padding: 20px;
}

li ul li {
  display: block;
}

.header ul li a ul li {
  display: none
}

#fb {
  position: relative;
  top: -200px;
}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="codigo 1,inicio.html">
  <img src="baner3.png" height="200px" width="1366px" title="inicio" />
</a>
<div id="header">
  <ul class="nave">
    <li> <a href="codigo 1,inicio.html"> INICIO </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="seccion 1.xml"> NOSOTROS</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="new 1.html">CONTRA EDITORIAL PRIMATE </a>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="articulos.html."> ARTICULOS </a> </li>
        <li> <a href? "publicaciones.html">PUBLICACIONES </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="columnas.html">COLUMNAS </a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="primatetv.html">  PRIMATE TV </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="radio primate.html"> RADIO PRIMATE </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="tienda.html"> TIENDA </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="donaciones.html">DONACIONES </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="contactanos.html">CONTACTANOS </a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="fb">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Tr%C3%ADada-Primate-1006588336127088/?ref=aymt_homepage_panel">
    <img src="facebook-icon-preview-1-400x400.png" height="30px" width="30px" title="fb primate">
  </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Lo que cambié fue:

```
#fb {
  position: relative;
  top: -150px;
}
```

**#** es para `id`, mientras que **.** es para `class` por ello si pones `div id="fb"` usas **#**

Y `top: -150px` marca qué tan separado estará el elemento del tope superior, que en este caso es negativo, también podrías usar `margin-top` [checa aquí las diferencias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036176/css-top-vs-margin-top).

Luego, es importante que después de una declaración se agrega el famoso **`;`** porque marca el final de la declaración, poner `position: relative top: 150px;` se leería:

- Propiedad: *position*
- Valor(es): *relative top: 150px*

Y no daría el resultado deseado. Aunque también es válido `position: relative; top: 150px;` pues la computadora es indiferente a los espacios en estos casos (inclusive podrías escribir toda una página web en una sola línea, pero usualmente no se hace así por la legibilidad).

Una recomendación es que **px** no es responsive design, algo que es casi esencial actualmente, es mejor usar **%** ó **vw**-**vh** ***v**iewport**w**idth* y ***v**iewport**h**eight*

Por último, acá está otra solución un poco más elaborada y con mejoras a toda la página:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
  body {
  background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: century;
  font-size: 20.05px;/*Usar vw o vh viewportwidth o viewportheight para responsive*/
}

ul,li {
 list-style: none;
}

.nave li a {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 5px;
  background-color: rgb( 0, 0, 0);
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.nave > li {
  float: left;
}

.nave li a:hover {
  background-color: rgb( 242, 179, 44);
}

li ul li {
  display: block;
}

.nave > li > ul{display: none;}
.nave > li:hover ul{display: block;}

#fb {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="position: relative;">
<a href="codigo 1,inicio.html">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oURrw.png" style="width:100%" title="inicio"> 
</a>
<div id="fb" style="width:15%">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Tr%C3%ADada-Primate-1006588336127088/?ref=aymt_homepage_panel">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconsimple-logotypes/512/github-512.png" title="fb primate" style="width: 100%">
  </a>
</div>
</div>
<div id="header">
  <ul class="nave">
    <li> <a href="codigo 1,inicio.html"> INICIO </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="seccion 1.xml"> NOSOTROS</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="new 1.html">CONTRA EDITORIAL PRIMATE </a>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="articulos.html."> ARTÍCULOS </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="publicaciones.html">PUBLICACIONES </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="columnas.html">COLUMNAS </a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="primatetv.html">  PRIMATE TV </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="radio primate.html"> RADIO PRIMATE </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="tienda.html"> TIENDA </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="donaciones.html">DONACIONES </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="contactanos.html">CONTÁCTANOS </a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

En el redireccionamiento de las imágenes, se podría poner un onclick="window.open()" y quitarle el `a href`, pero eso no sé qué tan recomendable sea.

Agregué un `div` más con `position: relative` (div padre) para que el div con `position: absolute` (div hijo) se pudiera ajustar bien al padre.

Las imágenes son simplemente de prueba, el ponerle `width: 100%` a la imagen automáticamente la asigna un height de modo que no se vea distorsionada, por ello aquí se omite eso, además de ser responsive.

P.D. Los atributos height y width ya son obsoletos, puedes pasar tu página por la w3c para revisar si tienes algo así o algún error.
También, HTML5 trae nuevas etiquetas como `nav` para la barra de navegación y otras cosas.